# Android Studio 3: how do I import a source code library into a project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The `build.gradle` in the `app`folder contains the following code:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':sclibrary')
}
```

The `settings.gradle` file in the project folder contains:

```
include ':app', ':sclibrary'
project(':sclibrary').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../sclibrary4')
```

When I synchronize my project I get an error that says "Missing dependencies: unable to find module with Gradle path ':sclibrary' (needed by module 'app'.)"

**EDIT:**

"sclibrary4" is located in the folder as the "sc" and "ScLite" applications; these applications use common code located in "sclibrary4"
[image: file structure]

When I try to use the "File>New>Import Module" command, I get the error message "This location is already imported" although

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this can be fixed with:

- remove project dependency from `settings.gradle` file
- remove dependency from `build.gradle`
- gradle sync
- Android Studio should show an info that a dependency has been removed
- add dependencies again

This worked for me on several occasions, e.g. with Android Studio 3.1.2

Comment: Not sure the order matters in all cases but for me, removing as stated and syncing, then adding the project dependency in `settings.gradle` first and syncing, then adding the dependency in the `build.grade` and syncing again did the trick for me